# nuspec contentFiles Example

Tags: nuget, nuspec

Yesterday NuGet 3.3 was released ([release notes](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-3.3)) and there is a new contentFiles element supported ([docs](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#content-files)).  However, I can't seem to get this working.

I'm using the NuGet.exe as the build process.  It is updated to v3.3.  I have also updated my Visual Studio to 2015 Update 1 and rebooted.

Here is my nuspec file (Hello.world.nuspec):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <metadata minClientVersion="3.3">
        <id>Hello.world</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <title>Greeting library</title>
        <authors>Timothy Klenke</authors>
        <description>Greetings for the world</description>
    </metadata>
    <contentFiles>
        <files include="*" />
    </contentFiles> 
</package>
```

I run from the command line using the following:

```
nuget.exe update -Self
nuget.exe pack Hello.world.nuspec
```

And I get the following:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'. Attempting to build package from  'Hello.world.nuspec'. The element 'package' in namespace  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element 'contentFiles' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'files' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'.

I think I am running all the latest versions that should support the new contentFiles XML element, but the tools don't seem to know about it.  What am I missing?  I know the files include attribute is garbage, but does someone have a full example nuspec file using the new contentFiles element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Element `<contentFiles>` has to be inside `<metadata>` according to [NuSpec reference](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference). So it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <metadata minClientVersion="3.3">
        <id>Hello.world</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <title>Greeting library</title>
        <authors>Timothy Klenke</authors>
        <description>Greetings for the world</description>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="*" />
        </contentFiles> 
    </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: That got around my XSD error.  Thanks.  I'm still having trouble with getting a C# code file to be included as content in a ASP.NET 5 solution.  Are there any examples out there of a full NUSPEC example file that does this?  I'm guess that the contentFiles element and files element have to be used in tandem somehow??

Comment: Peter, I guess you are having the same problem.  You've already asked that question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045140/deployment-of-contentfiles-in-nuget-3-3

Answer (score 4):

@Timothy,

You were right.  It is a combination having a metadata/contentFiles element as well as a definition in the files element.  I have a C# test utility library that needs to include PowerShell files in a projects output/bin folder when it is referenced using a PackageReference.  I will include the XML below for you.  I think you will be able to derive what you need from it.

*Special Note:
Be sure to get your language and framework values right in the path (i.e. yours will something like cs/net45/YourFile.cs).  I'm using any/any/MyFile.psm1 because I want the file to be treated as language and platform agnostic.  If I don't, I get code analysis errors on build.*

*Additionally, placing the files in a 'contentFiles' directory is important.*

(language and framework options defined in the .nuspec reference documentation)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files

```
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>SomeLibrary</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>SomeLibrary</title>
    <authors>Somebody</authors>
    <owners>Somebody</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Some library that does things I enjoy.</description>
    <releaseNotes />
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>PowerShell Testing</tags>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/SomePS.psd1" buildAction="none" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="any/any/SomePS.psm1" buildAction="none" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="*.dll" target="lib\net461" />
    <file src="*.pdb" target="lib\net461" />
    <file src="SomePS.psd1" target="contentFiles\any\any" />
    <file src="SomePS.psm1" target="contentFiles\any\any" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: I tried exactly same think , I see my files in the contentFiles directory but there are not copy in my bin/x64/Release directory. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

The "/" matters in the  node. It will not work if used:

```
<files include="any/any/x.dll" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
```

It must be:

```
<files include="any\any\x.dll" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
```

But it doesn't work for .NET framework??!

Comment: `<files include="../../.." ..>` works in dotnet pack from 2.1+.