# Deployment of contentFiles in NuGet 3.3

Tags: nuget, nuspec

NuGet 3.3 release few days ago supports `contentFiles`. I've created a package using `nuget.exe` according to [Nuspec reference](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference), but when I installed it to a project (based on ASP.NET 5 RC1), no files are added. Is there some complete example how it should work, please? Are there already some packages on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/) with `contentFiles`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently ASP.NET doesn't support contentFiles yet.

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/651